# How to add the click event on the icons in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am working on reactjs in which there are two icons . So I want to add click event on it . How can i do it.

```html
         <i>
              <TiGroupOutline size="150px" className="icon1"  />
            </i>
            <CardTitle>Students Info.</CardTitle>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="6">
          <Card body style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <i>
              <GoRequestChanges size="150px" className="icon2"/>
            </i>
```

Comment: Why don't you put them inside a transparent button which has `onClick` event handler?

Comment: I don't want  button in it , onClick event on icons looks better than buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing an `onClick` prop to `i`.

```js
<Col sm="6">
  <Card body style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
  <i onClick={handleClick('icon1')}>
    <GoRequestChanges size="150px" className="icon2"/>
  </i>
  ...
```

and then create a handler for this

```js
// React class
handleClick = (icon) => () => { // Note second arrow is required as we're invoking "onClick"
  console.log(icon); // "icon1"
  ... your logic
};
// React functional component
const handleClick = (icon) => () => { // Note second arrow is required as we're invoking "onClick"
  console.log(icon); // "icon1"
  ... your logic
};
```